# Insert row after percentage for each table in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some 100 tables. I need to insert row for each table after each %. How can I do this using excel macro?

```
        'Total  `Banglore`  `Delhi`
```

Q1. Age

`Base`         `'653`    `'77'`          `'86'`

18-19        `'35'`    `'15'`         `'22'

```
      '5%  '19%  '26%'
```

`20-24`        `'216'`     `'30'`      `'33'`

```
      '33%   '3    '38%'
```

Thanks,

Tanuvi

Comment: First tip for you... you have already asked some questions and got some answers which satisfied you. Use SO feature and 'close' these questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. :)

Comment: Thank you KazJaw for your info.

Comment: good job :) back to your question, what more (except % signs) distinguish that lines among other lines? are these lines containing string values or numeric values formatted to display % sign.

Comment: Frequency rows are having attributes (strings) in the first column but % rows are blanks in the 1st column. But after a table there will be blanks and next it will continue with Question text and "Base"

Comment: what does it mean that you have 100 tables, are they all in one sheet?

Comment: yes, all the tables are in same sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could could be helpful:
**EDIT** some comments added on OP request.

```
Sub Insert_blank_rows()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
        'this code will run from last till first row which is required when inserting rows
        'here we check last not-empty row to know which point to start from
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'start the loop from last not-empty direction first row
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        'if first cell in row is empty and there are some other not-empty cells
        If Len(Cells(i, 1)) = 0 And Application.CountBlank(Rows(i)) <> Columns.Count Then
            'we will insert empty row right below that row
            Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Some information:

-it works for active sheet

-I assumed that first column in your question is column A in your sheet

-code doesn't check if there is any % sign in the line but relies on other information you passed (first cell in row is empty and there are some other cells in the same row filled with values)

The following pictures presenting Before and After status.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you so much . It's working . Can you please elaborate each code in this macro.

Comment: so, please do not forget to mark answer as answer to inform others that your problem is solved.

Comment: and final tip for future use of SO, you could also use other features of SO like up-voting, down-voting, etc.

Comment: Ya sure. Thank you so much for your help...:)  Can you please suggest any good book to learn macro..

Comment: not sure if it's allowed here but try to explore [this site](http://spreadsheetpage.com/). And keep with StackOverflow, here is lot's of useful stuff to learn...